# How to change parent background color in expandablelistview when parent selected?

Tags: android

I want to change background color of selected position of parent  when it expand in expandablelistview and when I again press parent for collapse then it would again change background color at selected position.

I have tried below code, but it is working only for one parent when I am expand one parent and then expand second parent then application going crashed and showing null pointer exeaption.

```
  exp_family.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {


            Log.e("expanded Position", "" + groupPosition);


                exp_family.getChildAt(groupPosition).findViewById(R.id.rl_detail_member).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_bg);
                exp_family.getChildAt(groupPosition).findViewById(R.id.ic_exp_col).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_collaps_detail);

        }
    });

    exp_family.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Log.e("collapse Position", "" + groupPosition);

                exp_family.getChildAt(groupPosition).findViewById(R.id.rl_detail_member).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                exp_family.getChildAt(groupPosition).findViewById(R.id.ic_exp_col).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_expand);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Apply this code in your `ExpandableListAdapter` file

There are `getGroupView()` method which contain layout for parent for expandable list

Write Below code in your `getGroupView` method

Here i am changed image when group expanded or collapse

```
if(isExpanded)
{
   //You can Apply your code here like below code for change Background when group expanded
   img.setImageResource(R.drawable.less_sign);
}
else
{
   //You can Apply your code here like below code for change Background when group not expanded(collapsed)
   img.setImageResource(R.drawable.more_sign);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the override method getGroupView() write

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (isExpanded) {
                convertView.setBackgroundResource(USE YOUR BACKGROUND ON SELECTED);
            } else {
                convertView.setBackgroundResource(USE YOUR BACKGROUND ON UNSELECTED);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `ExpandableListview` adapter pass exp_family's reference. And then in adapter check.

```
if(exp_family.isGroupExpanded(position)){
    //Change color
} else {
   //Change back to previous color
}
```

And in if try to set your expanded background and else set your default background.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily. create a selector in drawable folder , example

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/log_gradient_bg" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/log_gradient_bg_hover" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/log_gradient_bg_hover" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
```

then add it expandablelistview parent background 
android:background="@drawable/log_spendable_list_selector"

you can see code 
https://github.com/RimonGazi/Android/blob/master/IPAEPS/res/drawable/log_spendable_list_selector.xml
and 
https://github.com/RimonGazi/Android/blob/master/IPAEPS/res/layout/log_spendable_parent.xml